# PowerShell large folder structure compare

Tags: powershell, compare, hashcode

I am looking to compare two large folder structures and compare the current state of a folder structure to a known good historical state, and I need the most performant option possible. 
The folder structure in question is an Autodesk "deployment", which is a bloated mess of an installer, with upwards of 15GB of data, 15,000+ files and 2500+ folders. And they are fragile, seemingly innocuous changes can break them. Ran into one the other day where the absence of a thumbs.DB file caused the entire install of Revit 2018 to fail. So, I want to be able to both copy deployments and do a hash compare of source and destination to ensure everything copied properly, and compare a current state with a historical state to make sure nothing has changed.

My initial thought was I could user `Get-ChildItem` the get a full listing of every folder and file name, then `Get-FileHash` that as a first step, then apportion all the file paths to an array to dole out to multiple jobs that `Get-FileHash` all the files, and then sum all the hashes to get a single hash for the folder. That can then be compared with the hash for the other folder, or the historical hash, to determine if anything has changed. I have benchmarked `Get-FileHash` running as a single threaded sequence on an example deployment, and it takes a reasonable couple of minutes, so multithreading that and reducing it by a factor of 4 or so on average would be quite doable.
That said, comparing two folder structures seems like the kind of thing that might be already implemented, and much faster, in Windows already. So before I go down that rabbit hole I thought it best to see if it's the right hole in the first place.

Comment: "comparing two folder structures seems like the kind of thing that might be already implemented" - most definitely. There are tools available already; e.g. [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/). If you use WinMerge you can specify filters to exclude files (such as `thumbs.db`) but other tools probably have similar features.

Comment: What about Compare-Object?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Ah, I should clarify, I need to do this natively, no third party apps. I don't control what is installed on the machines in question, other than mandating PS5.0 or higher. So third party solutions, so matter how good or affordable, are not something I can depend on. :(

Comment: @f6a4 I'll add that to my benchmarking. I would think that wouldn't be multithreaded by default, but worth a try.

Comment: i've never used the following, but it looks like it is designed to do what you want >>> New-FileCatalog — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/New-FileCatalog?view=powershell-5.1 <<<

Comment: No need for install. Just copy to a temporary directory and run it.

Comment: Also - you can also run `robocopy` in "log only" mode to get a list of differences.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I looked into that, but it seems robocopy only looks at datetime to determine if a file is different. And while date time will be different when the file is different, it can also be different when the file isn't, and in that situation I don't want to update. So, hashing seems like my best/only option.